# Find column and row indices of a matrix sorted in ascending order

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix

I'd like to solve this following task in Matlab:
If I have a general Matrix A, i.e:

```
A = [
1, 10, 8;
2, 2, 4;
3, 4, 50];
```

The values from min to max are:

```
1: pos. (1,1)
2: pos. (2,1)
2: pos. (2,2)
3: pos. (3,1)
4: pos. (2,3)
4: pos. (3,2)
...
```

So the output of this function will be two vectors:

```
x = [1,2,2,3,2,3,...];
y = [1,1,2,1,3,1,...];
```

corresponding to the row and column indices of the minumal values of the matrix A.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine  [**`sort`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) with [**`ind2sub`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
[vals,linpos] = sort(A(:))
[x,y] = ind2sub(size(A),linpos)
```

---

```
vals.' =  1     2     2     3     4     4     8    10    50
x.'    =  1     2     2     3     3     2     1     1     3
y,'    =  1     1     2     1     2     3     3     2     3
```

The difference to you desired output is caused by multiple occurences of the same number in your input data. If that matters, specify what rule should be applied.

Comment: No rule should be applied if multiple occurences appear. So your answer is the solution! Thank you very much